# How can I tell what "new privilege" I have earned?

Tags: bug, design, notifications

On upper left of my user page for DIY SE (`diy.stackexchange.com/users/...`), I see a text/graphic notification indicating that I have earned a "new privilege." But, it doesn't say what the "new privilege" is, or when I earned it.

I imagine that with a little sleuthing, I could discover it, bit I'm not even sure where to see a list of all the privileges I have earned.

[image: Notification in DIY.SE profile]

In any case, I recall (perhaps incorrectly) that when I have seen this notification in the past on other SE sites (or perhaps a notification about a different privilege), there was also (at least sometimes) some description of what the newly earned privilege was.

Again, I could be mistaken about that, perhaps the description I remember was with a notification about newly earned badges.

Is it normal (usual/typical) for the notification of a new privilege on a users' "user" page to include (or not include) a description of what the newly earned privilege was?

If it is not "normal", would it be reasonable to request this as an added feature?

Comment: The text "Edit community wikis" appears in the image you posted, but the contrast is not great so maybe you can't read it.  Is that the issue?  I think the contrast is better on the other SE sites.

Comment: @AriBrodsky - Oh, YES! I couldn't see that until you mentioned it. ... Nevermind =)

Comment: The contrast isn't great because the text isn't appearing in quite the right place... the pop-up is supposed to look more like the screenshots in [this unrelated bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290217/z-index-issue-with-you-earned-a-new-privilege). I'm retagging this so that it gets noticed by the right people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Privileges are listed under the help center. You can see them all [at this link](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have seen that, or a similar page before but I didn't know how to get to it. So, it seems I should assume the notification was about the highest privilege shown as "earned", which was: 100: edit community wiki, 100: create chat rooms. These privileges (and others) were all as a result of the initial 100 rep joining bonus.